# Is there a function to sort a bar graph by count instead of the default alphabetical in ggplot?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, count

I am trying to make a bar graph using ggplot2

the data looks like this (there are about 10000 observations) and i have around 60 different subgroups.

```
ID        subgroup            patient_group
1866      cancer              1
1877      heart failure       1
1878      cancer              2
1879      infection           1
...       ...
```

What I would like to do is sort the subgroups by count instead of alphabetically, so the graph is easier to read. this is my code so far.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = subgroup, fill = patient_group)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Count of Subgroups of patients") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  labs(fill = "Emerge Version")
```

Is there a way to reorder the bars without having to make a new dataframe for the subgroups?
Thanks!

Comment: `aes(x = reorder(factor(subgroup), subgroup, length))`

Comment: Or with `library(forcats)`, `aes(x = fct_infreq(subgroup))`.